# How to wait for $firebaseArray data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

Below is my firebase query that works fine:

```
var orderedPlayers = databaseService.players.orderByChild("id");
```

My intention is to then have the point total of each player to be added together:

```
            $scope.sum = function(items, prop){
            return items.reduce( function(a, b){
            return a + b[prop];
            }, 0);
            };

            $scope.selectedPlayers = $firebaseArray (orderedPlayers);
            $scope.totalGoals = $scope.sum($scope.players, 'goals');
```

The issue is that when i change the number of goals directly in the firebase database, there is a real time updating of the goals under each player as displayed in my scope but there is no corresponding change in the resulting total number of goals.

i.e. `$scope.selectedPlayers updates in real time` but `$scope.totalGoals` only updates after refreshing the page.

Is it possible to have the latter update in realtime as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to watch but try this:

```
$scope.$watch('players', (newVal, oldVal)=>{
   $scope.totalGoals = $scope.sum(newVal, 'goals');
});
```

Now this will watch for changes in $scope.players you might need some other variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$scope.$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) to check for a value to change. Since you're looking for a value on $scope to change, the syntax would be this:

```
$scope.$watch('players', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.totalGoals = $scope.sum(newValue, 'goals');
})
```

It's not needed in your case, but if you want to watch some arbitrary variable instead of something on $scope, you can replace the 'players' string with a function that returns the thing you want to check for changes:

```
let something = {
    somethingElse: 'hello world'
};
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return something.somethingElse;
}, function (newValue, oldValue) {});
```

Be aware that $watch statements (whether the first style or the second style) will cause code to be run on every call of the digest cycle to check for changes, so having a large number of these will degrade performance.

Comment: the syntax your provided did not work. for some reason it didn't return the result of the sum function

Comment: @DejiJames are you talking about the second example? That was a hypothetical case where you wanted to watch an object that's not on the scope. Since it's a hypothetical, i left the second function blank, and so it doesn't do anything. The first function tells angular what it should be watching for to change; the second function says what to do when it changes.

Comment: no I was talking about the first example. The {{totalPoints}} was blank in the view.

Comment: if your template says {{totalPoints}}, then that's not suprising. The variable is named totalGoals. But if that was just a typo in your comment, then we'll need to see your template to be able to debug your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the promise returned with the [`$loaded()` method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-loaded):

```
$scope.selectedPlayers = $firebaseArray (orderedPlayers);

var qPromise = $scope.selectedPlayers.$loaded();

qPromise.then(function(dataArray) {
    console.log(dataArray);
    $scope.totalGoals = $scope.sum($scope.players, 'goals');
});
```

It is important to realize that the `$firebaseArray` method immediately returns an empty reference. Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data. The sum can only be computed after it arrives from the server.